# How to transfer coins between L1 and L2 via web3.js or ethers.js?

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, layer-2, bridge

How to do it? Programmatically.

Does it always require a bridge? Or can it be done in other way too?

I haven't found any difinitive answer to this anywhere.